# IN mysql function group_concat change separator dynamically

Tags: mysql, group-concat, separator

I want to use separator for  group_concat() function in mysql.But I want to change the separator  dynamically.I mean the separator  value is coming from a table and that is different for every row.

I couldn't found any solution for that please help me.

Comment: Probably an indication that you have a huge problem with your data. For this you need dynamic sql

Comment: IN other words I am passing the separator value in parameter then how to use that please help..

Comment: I got the solution:we can use any separator inside ' ' but at last replace with that one which we are passing.

Comment: @SaritaTewari, faced the same problem. Could you clarify your solution, please?

Answer (score 3):

Finally got a solution.

Let's say we have some MySQL routine. We need to `GROUP_CONCAT` some value with special `SEPARATOR` (default is ','). But `SEPARATOR` isn't static, it's got from another table, for ex. from some "settings" table.

```
DECLARE url_delimiter VARCHAR(255);

SELECT catalog_url_delimiter
INTO url_delimiter
FROM settings;
```

We can't use variable as SEPARATOR parameter directly:

```
-- doesn't work
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`some_table`.id SEPARATOR url_delimiter)
FROM <some query>
```

But we can use some dummy separator and replace it with valid as below:

```
SELECT 
  REPLACE(
    GROUP_CONCAT(`some_table`.id SEPARATOR 'some-tricky-dummy-separator'), 
    'some-tricky-dummy-separator', 
    url_delimiter
  )
FROM <some query>
```